# Multiple volumetric lights

Tags: lighting, post-processing, volumetric-light

I recently read this GPU GEMS 3 article [Volumetric Light Scattering as a Post-Process](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-ii-light-and-shadows/chapter-13-volumetric-light-scattering-post-process). I like the idea to add volumetric light property to realtime render i'm working on. Question is will it work for multiple lights? Our renderer uses one render pass per light and uses additive blending to sum incoming light.

I'm mostly convinced that it have to work nice. Do you agree? Maybe there can be problem where light rays crosses each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit ambiguous. Will it work? Sure it will. You can probably squeeze it down to one pass that traces against all lights, even though you use one pass per light. Can you add your lights to a list and do a post process batch where your lights are in a list?

Will it look good? That's the problem. It's not really easy to answer and depend a lot on your art direction and how intense you want the effect from each light to be.